# i want get data from table sql

Tags: php, sql

i have a table register with email and username colums.

```
> ex - username  email 
>      test      test@gmail.com
>      new       new@gmail.com

 
SELECT * FROM Register WHERE email='test@gmail.com'
```

I can get this colom ,but i cant select username.i want assign username to variable

Comment: What do you mean you can't select the username..? Some PHP code would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this if you use MySQL :

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT username, email FROM MyTable";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "username: " . $row["username"]. " - email: " . $row["email"]. "<br>";
  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

In my opinion you're probably a beginner with web development with databases.
I recommend you w3chools. You can reed various examples in this site: 
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, but if you are new with database I recommend you to start with PDO instead of mysqli.

```html
<?php
  //Db connection
  function pdo_connect_mysql() {
    $DATABASE_HOST = 'localhost';
    $DATABASE_USER = 'root';
    $DATABASE_PASS = '';
    $DATABASE_NAME = 'phpcrud';
    try {
        return new PDO('mysql:host=' . $DATABASE_HOST . ';dbname=' . $DATABASE_NAME . ';charset=utf8', $DATABASE_USER, $DATABASE_PASS);
    } catch (PDOException $exception) {
        // If there is an error with the connection, stop the script and display the error.
        exit('Failed to connect to database!');
    }
}

  // User Input
  $username = 'john';
  $email = 'john@gmail.com';
  
  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM register WHERE username = ? email = ?';
  $stmt = pdo_connect_mysql() ->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute([$username, $email]);
  $register = $stmt->fetchAll();
?>
```